# How to use SUBSTRING to extract data using 2 different delimiters?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Dealing with a table that has a column that is a string.  Here are some examples of what the strings look like:

```
 Fee Prorated 68%  -  $1.00  x 76
 Fee - Prorated 50% ($1.10 x 292)
 Fee - Prorated 50% ($1.00 x 242)
 Fee - Prorated 13% ($1.00 x 39)
 Prorated  Fee 45.16%  $1.00 x 256
 Fee - Prorated 26% ($1.00 x 56)
 Fee- Prorated 51.6%  $1.00 x 66
 Fee - Prorated 94% ($1.15 x 48)
 Fee - Prorated 52% ($1.10 x 120)
 Fee - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 304)
 Fee - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 304)
 Fees - prorated 46.67% ($1.50 x 230)
 Fees - prorated 23% ($1.25 x 989)
 Fees - prorated 87% ($1.25 x 348)
 Fees - prorated 48% ($1.25 x 210)
 Fees ($1.50 x 64) Prorated 30%
 Fees - prorated 30% ($1.50 x 51)
 Fees ($1.25 x 341) - Prorated 71%
 Fees - Prorated 58% ($1.50 x 196)
 Fees - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 224)
 Fees - Prorated 61%($1.50 x 50)
```

I need to get a substring that is just the percentage so I can convert it to a decimal and then multiply by that amount.

I am at a loss of how to do this except to try and use the % as a delimited and grabbing everything to the left of it until it gets to a space character - problem is I have no idea how do to it

Comment: Use regexp: `/Prorated \n+%/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `charindex()`, `reverse()`, and `left()` to determine the parameters for `substring()`:

```
select 
    col
  , substring(
      col
    , charindex('%',col) - (charindex(' ',reverse(left(col,charindex('%',col)))+' ')-2)
    ,(charindex(' ',reverse(left(col,charindex('%',col)))+' ')-2)
    ) as Prorated
from t
where charindex('%',col)>0
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GKVB60235

returns:

```
+--------------------------------------+----------+
|                 col                  | Prorated |
+--------------------------------------+----------+
| Fee Prorated 68%  -  $1.00  x 76     | 68       |
| Fee - Prorated 50% ($1.10 x 292)     | 50       |
| Fee - Prorated 50% ($1.00 x 242)     | 50       |
| Fee - Prorated 13% ($1.00 x 39)      | 13       |
| Prorated  Fee 45.16%  $1.00 x 256    | 45.16    |
| Fee - Prorated 26% ($1.00 x 56)      | 26       |
| Fee- Prorated 51.6%  $1.00 x 66      | 51.6     |
| Fee - Prorated 94% ($1.15 x 48)      | 94       |
| Fee - Prorated 52% ($1.10 x 120)     | 52       |
| Fee - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 304)     | 10       |
| Fee - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 304)     | 10       |
| Fees - prorated 46.67% ($1.50 x 230) | 46.67    |
| Fees - prorated 23% ($1.25 x 989)    | 23       |
| Fees - prorated 87% ($1.25 x 348)    | 87       |
| Fees - prorated 48% ($1.25 x 210)    | 48       |
| Fees ($1.50 x 64) Prorated 30%       | 30       |
| Fees - prorated 30% ($1.50 x 51)     | 30       |
| Fees ($1.25 x 341) - Prorated 71%    | 71       |
| Fees - Prorated 58% ($1.50 x 196)    | 58       |
| Fees - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 224)    | 10       |
| Fees - Prorated 61%($1.50 x 50)      | 61       |
+--------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: I think this is pretty close, I may have implemented something incorrectly but I get an error

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function. Also only 145 rows returned, I should have had 1136 rows

Comment: @DRT You may not have a space before the `%` or you may be missing the `%`. Try the updated code.

Comment: The updated code worked perfectly - marking as answer, thank you so much @SqlZim

Answer (score 0):

Fetching data from between strings and deriving your processing on it is riskier and not beneficial in long run. So I would suggest you to find how is the `%` value getting loaded in the column and see if you can have a separate column to load it, along side your table.

If it is not at all possible, and also if string pattern is not fixed, then you can do it with combination of `charindex`,`substring` and `reverse`.

I would suggest you to check the `regex` approach also as mentioned in comments, as I am afraid that so many string function might slow down the query. So compare both approach and go with faster one.

[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/XFOJK57368)

```
 SELECT 
 reverse
    (substring
        (reverse
            (substring
                (col,1,charindex('%',col,1))
            ),2,charindex(' ',reverse
                                (substring(col,1,charindex('%',col,1))
                                ),1
                         )-2
        )
    ) as percentage
FROM
  (SELECT 'Fee Prorated 68%  -  $1.00  x 76' AS col
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Fee - Prorated 50.0987% ($1.10 x 292)') t
```

Output

```
percentage
----------
68
50.0987
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with a Parse/Split function.

Here we use a [SPACE] as the delimiter, but with a little twist to ensure capture.  Before we pass the string into a the parser, we replace the [PERCENT] with [PERCENT]||[SPACE]

**Example**

```
Select A.*
      ,Pcnt = replace(B.RetVal,'||','')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K](replace(A.SomeCol,'%','%|| '),' ') B
 Where RetVal Like '%||'
```

**Returns**

```
SomeCol                              Pcnt
Fee Prorated 68% - $1.00 x 76       68%
Fee - Prorated 50% ($1.10 x 292)    50%
Fee - Prorated 50% ($1.00 x 242)    50%
Fee - Prorated 13% ($1.00 x 39)     13%
Prorated Fee 45.16% $1.00 x 256     45.16%
Fee - Prorated 26% ($1.00 x 56)     26%
Fee- Prorated 51.6% $1.00 x 66      51.6%
Fee - Prorated 94% ($1.15 x 48)     94%
Fee - Prorated 52% ($1.10 x 120)    52%
Fee - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 304)    10%
Fee - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 304)    10%
Fees - prorated 46.67% ($1.50 x 230)46.67%
Fees - prorated 23% ($1.25 x 989)   23%
Fees - prorated 87% ($1.25 x 348)   87%
Fees - prorated 48% ($1.25 x 210)   48%
Fees ($1.50 x 64) Prorated 30%      30%
Fees - prorated 30% ($1.50 x 51)    30%
Fees ($1.25 x 341) - Prorated 71%   71%
Fees - Prorated 58% ($1.50 x 196)   58%
Fees - Prorated 10% ($1.25 x 224)   10%
Fees - Prorated 61%($1.50 x 50)     61%
```

**The UDF if Intersted**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(25))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
           cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d) A ),
           cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter),
           cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By A.N)
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(Substring(@String, A.N, A.L)))
    From   cte4 A
);
--Orginal Source http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse-8K]('John||Cappelletti||was||here','||')
```